# PHP Filtering Isotope

Tags: php, filtering, jquery-isotope

First of all, sorry for my english i trying to do my best to be clearest.

I used Isotope to filter some information as a result of a query. Its working fine but now i want to add the posibility of filtering with multiple criteria.

I have the following filter buttons:

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Todos</button>
              <button class="button" data-filter="rcivil">Resp. Civil</button>
              <button class="button" data-filter="cbasica">C.Basica</button>
              <button class="button" data-filter="tcompleto">T.Completo</button>
              <button class="button" data-filter="triesgo">T.Riesgo</button>
            </div>
```

With this Javascript:

```
        // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.grid1',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows',
      getSortData: {
        codigo: '.codigo',
        cuota: '.cuota',
      }
    });
    $grid.isotope({
      sortBy: 'cuota',
      sortAscending: true
    });

    // filter functions
    var filterFns = {
      // show if number is greater than 50
      numberGreaterThan50: function() {
        var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
        return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
      },
      // responsabilidad civil
      rcivil: function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.codigo').text();
        return name.match( /\b(A1|A2|A3|A4|A22|A|A10|A10 PROMO)\b/ );
      },
      // cobertura basica
      cbasica: function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.codigo').text();
        return name.match( /\b(B2|B1|B|B1\-80|B\-80|E|E1)\b/ );
      },
      // terceros completos
      tcompleto: function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.codigo').text();
        return name.match( /\b(C1|C2|C|C2\-80|C1\-80|Sigma Importados|S0|LB1|LB|CF)\b/ );
      },
      // todo riesgo
      triesgo: function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.codigo').text();
        return name.match( /\b(T9|T14|T13|T2|TD|TD1|TD3)\b/ );
      }
    };
    // bind filter button click
    $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
      // use filterFn if matches value
      filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
      $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });

    // bind sort button click
    $('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
      $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
    });

    // change is-checked class on buttons
    $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
      var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
      $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
      });
    });
```

What i should do if i want to select more than option at the same time? for example "rcivil" and "cbasica" simultaneously.

Any help or idea will be more than appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try using checkbox.

[Example 1](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/btFfG)

[Example 2](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JGKyrY)

```
You will understand from the links.
```